# To create Square-Grid Button Layout

Tags: android

I was thinking how I can create a square-grid layout in android where in each block act as a Button.

e.g
Look at this

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723002546/https://www.nctm.org/mathforum/)

In this layout, I want each block to act as a Button.
Also, I want the size to be dynamic i.e. if I enter 4, it gives me 4X4 grid. If I enter 5, it gives me 5X5 grid.

Please give me suggestions how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you mentioned that the layout needs to be dynamic in nature may I suggest `Tabular Layout`. In your XML add `ID` to `TableLayout`. And while run time add `TableRows`.

I believe it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this posts will help you:

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677
- http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php

To increase spacing beetwen items use:

### Vertical

> `android:layout_columnSpan`
>
> The column span: the difference between the right and left boundaries
>   delimiting the group of cells occupied by this view. The default is
>   one. See GridLayout.Spec.
>
> Must be an integer value, such as "100".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol
>   layout_columnSpan. Related Methods

### Horizontal

> `android:layout_rowSpan`
>
> The row span: the difference between the top and bottom boundaries
>   delimiting the group of cells occupied by this view. The default is
>   one. See GridLayout.Spec.
>
> Must be an integer value, such as "100".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol
>   layout_rowSpan. Related Methods

Comment: Thank you for your the Solution!
It helped me a lot. 
But I have another question related to Grid Layout. 
How can I increase/decrease the horizontal/vertical spacing in the Grid?

Comment: Sorry If I am wrong, but these attributes/methods are not available for GridLayout. I think they are for GridView.